# There was no portal room in my stronghold. How can I find another stronghold?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I need to find another stronghold because the one that the Eye of ender took me to does not have a portal. How can I find another stronghold that has a portal room?

I'm playing v1.16 of Minecraft.

Comment: Is [tag:minecraft-legacy-console] (which hasn't been supported since December) really the correct edition?

Answer (score 1):

**Your stronghold may still have a portal room. However, it may be in a room that's disconnected from the rest of the chambers you explored.** I've personally experienced this. I eventually found the portal by looking for parts of my stronghold where the room generation didn't line up well, then knocking out the walls in the general area. I eventually found a disconnected part of the stronghold that had a portal.

**If you want to find another stronghold, and are comfortable using third-party tools**, you can use [the Stronghold Finder on Chunkbase](https://www.chunkbase.com/apps/stronghold-finder) to find the locations of other strongholds in your seed.

**If you'd rather not use third-party tools**, you have some work ahead of you. [Depending on which version of Minecraft your playing, you're guaranteed a certain number of strongholds within a certain number of blocks of the world's origin coordinates (x=0, z=0, not spawn)](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stronghold). If you head to your world's origin from your existing stronghold, and keep going, your Eyes of Ender should start directing you to another stronghold.

*Note*: As of May '20, Mojang stated that, in Bedrock, [it's intended that not all strongholds will have portals](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-75181). This contradicts the Minecraft Wiki, which currently claims that [all strongholds are guaranteed to have a portal](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stronghold#Rooms).